# How to filter Hadoop result output

Tags: hadoop

My reducer:

```
public static class CustomReducer extends Reducer<Int256Writable, ByteWritable, IntWritable, Int256Writable>
```

Based on wether the result IntWritable is > 1, I want to filter the output of Hadoop so that all those KV pairs will not be written to output where the condition applies.

Up until now I'm using a simple TextOutputFormat but I'm planning to change to binary soon.

How can I filter the KV pairs before outputting them?

Answer (score 0):

Holy shit I'm stupid. For the record: Simply don't context.write the result in your reducer if you don't want it to appear in the output.

Comment: since this was a simple / obvious answer, I suggest you delete the question.